# How to create binding property in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have one drawing object SkiaView.
I create many SkiaView in xaml file so I am looking for a way to passing custom property to my SkiaView.

I tried this:

(Author : https://codemilltech.com/back-to-school-adding-a-custom-bindable-property-to-xamarin-forms/)

---

```
      public static readonly BindableProperty TestVarProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<SkiaView, string>(rv => rv.TestVar,"None", 
            BindingMode.TwoWay, (bindable,value)=> { return true; },
            (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => {

                var thisView = (SkiaView)bindable;},
    (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => {},
    (bindable, value) => {
        return value;
    }, (bindable) => {
        return ">Error<";
    });

    public string TestVar
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestVarProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestVarProperty, value); }
    }
```

But this returns string "none", I would like get and use my TestVar set in xaml.
So if anybody have an idea for passing property to an object without Bindable Property I take it.

Comment: Can you post the code showing what you assign to `TestVar`?

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question you should post it *as an answer* rather than editing it into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, i have change the code below like this

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TestVarProperty =
   BindableProperty.Create<SkiaView, string>(rv => rv.TestVar, null,
       BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

    public string TestVar
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestVarProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestVarProperty, value); }
    }
```

And it's working !